# Using pretrained model for different resolution image

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a pre-trained deep learning model which does not use any pooling or dimensionality reduction layers on an image resolution of 1024*400. Now,  I wish to use this for inference over 4k resolution images. Is it viable in terms of accuracy or at the first place would it even work without any errors, or I should fine tune it first on this resolution ( if its possible now). Any help would be greatly appreciated  Thanks

Comment: You can just resize the images to fit the input shape of your model.

Comment: Won't it actually hamper the accuracy due to lesser information. I am actually working on extracting motion vectors between two frames of a video.

Comment: A higher resolution might provide more details and more robust features to learn but comes at the cost of significantly longer training times and greater cost and no guarantee that the model will even be better at making predictions. [BaiduVision](https://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/1501/1501.02876v1.pdf) uses larger input dimensions compared to ResNet but ResNet still gives a better increase of predictive performance compared to its computational cost to due to it having more layers.